# rails action_controller usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I digg into some project with long development history

Maybe it's newbe question:

For specific controller I found thats it inherited from **ActionController**
like so

```
class GraphController < ActionController
end
```

and seems it used for API cause when I add some actions there they shown without layout
can anybody point me to some good article about ActionController usage.
I check documentation but can't find any good explanation for tats stuff

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html contains a good description of ActionController basics.